# Why forms.ModelForm loss data from FileField in Django 2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x, forms, django-forms

I have a `CustomForm` that extends from `forms.ModelForm` and use a `FileField` like this:

```
avatar = forms.FileField(required=False, label="avatar")
```

When I save the model, everything works, and file was saved in directory. But when I re-enter in view (file is over there), and just click in "Save", the file is lost. My `views.py` is:

```
def edit_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
    else:
        user= User\
            .objects\
            .get_or_create(user=request.user,
                           defaults={'name':request.user.first_name,
                                     'email':request.user.email})
        form = CustomForm(instance=user)

        return render(request, 'user.html', {'form':form, 'user':user})
```

I'm using `Python 3.6` and `Django 2.0`.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'myprofile' %}"
                              class="form-horizontal" role="form"
                              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {% for field in form %}
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-10">
                                        {% render_field field class+="form-control" %}
                                        {% if field.errors %}
                                            <br/>
                                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                                                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                                                    <p><strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong></p>
                                                </div>

                                            {% endfor %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% if field.help_text %}
                                        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'save' %}" >
                        </form>
```

Comment: Can you also show your HTML? Is your form uploading multipart data?

Comment: I put the HTML in my Edit